# Apache Kafka - Advisory Message

Tags: apache-kafka

Apache Kafka has option "Advisory Message", similar to ActiveMQ?

ActiveMQ Advisory Message -> http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no such functionality. Instead of managing cluster with advisory messages, kafka relies on zookeeper and whenever some action is required (e.g. delete topic, perform rebalance) it creates appropriate "command" node in zk.

Having said this, kafka exposes a lot of it's underpinnings as [JMX accessible statistics](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#monitoring).